# SQL Server 2016 SSIS packages failing when deployed using VS2015 SQL Server Data Tools v14

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 14.0.25341.01

SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61707.300

SQL Server 2016 13.0.4435.0

I recently had a message in VS2015 that a update for SQL Server Data Tools was available.  I decided to download and install it and now packages I deploy to SQL 2016 no longer work.

I do not know what my version of SQL Server Data Tools was before I installed the update, but I do know that inside my SSIS Project, I now see the TargetServerVersion option of SQL 2017 (used to only go to SQL 2016).

I confirmed my project (which is the project I use for all my SSIS packages and have since we deployed SQL 2016) is still set to TargetServerVersion SQL 2016.  The project is set to Project Deployment Mode, and I've always deployed by opening a package, and clicking File -> Save Copy of filename.dtsx As... and then deploying to target SQL.  Nothing has changed in our environment outside of my upgrade of SQL Server Data Tools.

Here's the error I receive when I try to run the package:

```
Executed as user: DOMAIN\ProxySvc. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.
Started:  3:32:33 PM
Error: 2017-09-28 15:32:33.37
Code: 0xC0010018
Source: Package_Name
Description: Error loading value "<DTS:ConnectionManagers xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"><DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[SERVER A]"  DTS:CreationName="OLEDB" DTS:DTSID="{E5D397C2-477A-4E04-B930-613DDE14A054}" DTS:ObjectName="SERVER A"><DTS:ObjectData>" from node "DTS:ConnectionManagers".  
End Error
Could not load package "\Maintenance Plans\Package_Name" because of error 0xC0010014.  
Description: One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.
Source:
Started:  3:32:33 PM  Finished: 3:32:33 PM  Elapsed:  0.109 seconds.
The package could not be loaded.
The step failed.
```

The packages will however work if I deploy them using DtUtil from the SQL 2016 Dev Edition I have installed locally.  For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil" /FILE "C:\filename.dtsx" /DestServer SERVERNAME/INSTANCE /Encrypt SQL;"Maintenance Plans\Package_Name";2;PKG_PA$$
```

Has anyone else had issue with this?  I can't be the only person deploying package this way that suddenly had the packages stop working when deployed in VS2015 and SQL Server Data Tools.

I've also opened a Connect for [this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3141694).

**Edit:** I tried Visual Studio 2017 with the preview edition of SQL Server Data Tools for it.  I get the same issue.  Package deploys fine, but the package will not run.

**Edit 2:** If I create an empty package, it runs successfully (granted doing nothing).  If I create an empty package with nothing but a single OLEDB connection, it fails with the message above.  It also fails with the same message with an empty package and only a single ADO.NET connection.

**Edit 3:** I deployed two packages.  One using SSDT (that fails to run on the server with error above) and another with DTUTIL that executes on the server fine.  The packages are the exact same except for how they were copied to the server.  I then used DTUTIL to copy the package back to my machine and compared them.  Outside of the DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion version differences, the only other change is the EncryptionMethod Algorithm.  The one deployed using SSDT says:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
```

And the one deployed using DTUTIL:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
```

Obviously the Salt, IV, and CipherValues are different but I wonder if the encryption being applied by SSDT when deploying is causing the issue.

Comment: Update SSDT to the latest version. It's a separate, free product. [The latest version for VS 2015 is 17.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

Comment: I've already done that.  Please look at my version number and the version number from the link you posted.  They match.

Comment: I loooove SSDT version numbers. On VS 2017, the SSIS tools version is .... an empty string, but at least it works.

Comment: The error code is 0xC0010014. Googling for it at least one answer mentions [running on the 32 vs 64-bit runtime](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2010/06/16/why-package-load-error-0xc0010014-in-cpackageloadfromxml-error-appears-while-trying-to-run-an-ssis-package/). You can't mix OLEDB and runtimes  of different bitness.

Comment: Yes.  I've tried every solution that comes up when using Google, which is why I made a post here.

Comment: And *what* is the driver, what is the runtime? Is this an Excel source perhaps? Have you installed the correct ACE package on the server?

Comment: Try creating a new package in 2016 compatibility mode with a simple dataflow using the same source/destination. If it works, you can compare the source differences to find out what caused the problem.

Comment: It's SQL Server OLE DB connection.  I can create a blank package with nothing in it but that single OLE DB connection and it fails with the message above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue. What solved it for me was this: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/12/ There's a missing assembly reference in the devenv.exe.config file. If you deploy via command line or using the ISDeploymentWizard, that's probably your issue.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I added the following to me devenv.exe.config under the assemblyBinding section:               <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServicesEnum" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.0.0-14.100.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
              </dependentAssembly> -- I'm still getting the error from my original question after redeploying.  Did adding that assembly help you to deploy to SQL 2016? Blog seems focused on vNext.

Comment: In addition, I do not get an error when using 'Save a copy of filename.dtsx as...'.  It appears to deploy fine, the package simply will not run on the server.  I do not think this fix is applicable to my issue at all.